# How to remove or disable SQL Telemetry (sqlceip)

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have SQL 2019 Enterprise Edition patched to CU18 installed on a 2-node Windows 2022 cluster and configured with an Availability Group. I have been investigating an unusual and persistent behaviour of the cluster nodes when a Primary node is rebooted.

The behaviour is that when a Primary node is rebooted, as expected, an automatic failover happens to the previously secondary replica (synchronous commit), however, the SQL services on the rebooted node take between 10 - 30 minutes to start. The Engine service in Configuration Manager stays in 'Change Pending' state during this delay and then when it finally starts, the Agent has to be manually started.

During the delay, there is no errorlog produced, no sql server process in Task Manager, no  related logs in Event Viewer.

I have done a lot of research on the internet but not found anything helpful yet. I am now currently using Process Monitor to monitor what happens during the delay. I found that no sqlservr process is captured by Procmon until the sql engine service starts up. I however also found that most of the sql processes captured during that delay are **sqlceip** processes with various results. Some results are 'NAME NOT FOUND' (Operation = RegOpenKey and Path is given) or 'PATH NOT FOUND' (Operation = Create File), or 'BUFFER OVERFLOW' (Operation = RegQueryValue) etc and quite a few of such results. I had also captured the SQL processes **before** rebooting the node and all the sqlceip results then were 'SUCCESS'

So, my guess is that during the delay period, sqlceip is trying to do somethings and not a happy bunny due to some reasons, therefore causing the delay. Now, because I don't quite know how to handle these results and because I have seen SQL Telemetry (sqlceip) cause an issue in a SQL FCI before, I am thinking of removing it altogether. I tried disabling it under Error Reporting and Usage in Start Programs but I still have the processes in Procmon.

I will appreciate any helpful suggestions on how to investigate/fix this problem please. As I said, I am thinking of removing/diabling sqlceip altogether if I can know how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Configure usage and diagnostic data collection for SQL Server (CEIP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/sql-server/usage-and-diagnostic-data-configuration-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017):

> Enterprise customers can configure Group Policy settings to opt in or
> out of usage and diagnostic data collection. This is done by
> configuring a registry-based policy. The relevant registry subkey and
> settings are as follows:
>
> For SQL Server instance features:
>
> Subkey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
> Server{InstanceID}\CPE
>
> RegEntry name = CustomerFeedback
>
> Entry type DWORD: 0 is opt out; 1 is opt in
>
> {InstanceID} refers to the instance type and instance, as in the
> following examples:
>
> MSSQL14.CANBERRA for SQL Server 2017 Database engine and Instance name
> of "CANBERRA" MSAS14.CANBERRA for SQL Server 2017 Analysis Services
> and Instance name of "CANBERRA" For SQL Server Reporting Services 2017
> and later instance features:
>
> Subkey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
> Server\SSRS\CPE
>
> RegEntry name = CustomerFeedback
>
> Entry type DWORD: 0 is opt out; 1 is opt in
>
> For all shared features:
>
> Subkey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
> Server{Major Version}
>
> RegEntry name = CustomerFeedback
>
> Entry type DWORD: 0 is opt out; 1 is opt in

Comment: That is very helpful @ErikDarling, thank you, much appreciated. Do you or anyone else know please, by any chance, if my thought is a good idea for the issue I described? Has anyone had this kind of situation before please?